# Two Network cards and ip forwarding

Tags: networking, routing

I want to make "Ubuntu 11.10" act as a router.

I have two LAN interfaces.

Let's say interface A' IP is `172.16.1.10` ; 
interface B's IP is `192.168.1.10`.

How can I configure Ubuntu so that 172.16.1.1 can connect to 192.168.1.1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds as if you are configuring a router.

You only need to make a few changes to enable IP forwarding

Enable IP forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Configure iptables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

See also [Ubuntu Wiki router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router)

You will likely want to learn a little about iptables

[Linux Firewalls Using IPTables](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch14_%3a_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables)

If all that seems a bit overwhelming, may I suggest you consider one of the linux distributions that are built to act as a router ? I like smoothwall, but there are others to choose from.

[smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org/)

Firewall specific distros will handle most or all of the configuration for you and most come with a web based interface to make it ever easier.

Comment: It work like a magic. Now packet from 172.16.2.100 (eth0) go through 192.168.1.1 (eth1) , however packet from 192.168.1.1 cannot reach 172.16.2.100. Are there any symmetric configuration that packet can reach to both side. I try to configure iptalbes with reverse configuration, but still didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want ? Sounds as if you need to configure iptables.

Comment: Right now, the 172.16.1.1 one can ping to router (the real router not Ubuntu 192.168.1.1) but that router can't ping to the 172.168.1.1
Imagine that I have 2 computer (A, B) and a router (C)

Comment: Right now, the 172.16.1.1 one can ping to router (the real router not Ubuntu 192.168.1.1) but that router can't ping to the 172.168.1.1
Imagine that I have 2 computer (A, B) and a router (C)
A has IP 172.16.1.1 
B has IP 192.168.1.10, and 172.16.1.10
C has IP 192.168.1.1
A connect to B
B connect to C
A can talk (ping) to C via B
but C can't talk(ping) to A via B << my problem
A can talk to C due to your solution
So, what should I do next to make C can talk to A (Reverse configuration?)

Comment: You will need a similar configuration. You really need to read an understand iptables if you are going to configure your router. You need to understand what those 3 rules I gave you perform. If you are going to allow all traffic in an out, then what is the point of configuring a router / subnet ? The answer to that question will configure iptables.

Comment: Ok , I will study about iptables. Thank you very much.